# How comes G = H'*H is not positive definite in python where H is full column rank?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm tring to solve a QP problem with `quadprog` library in python. It returns:
`matrix G is not positive definite`
But it is defined as `G=np.dot(H.T,H)` where `H` is a 500-by-13 mat and is full column rank. See this:
[G turns out to be deficient-rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leenK.png)

I know it might be a numerical issue so I applied `np.set_printoptions(precision=16)` to imporve precision but it didn't work. So I just wonder what's wrong with my code and how I can tune my code.

ps. all mat here are real number mat

Comment: It seems like it is not a programming issue, but rather mathematical one.

Comment: As for the problem: not sure and just guessing, but could it be that you only transpose, whereas you should conjugate transpose?

Comment: @Maciek thanks for commenting. But both H and G are real number matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, this is probably a numerical precision issue.  When you compute `dot(H.T, H)`, elements of `H` are multiplied together.  If some of those elements are sufficiently small, their products can be so small that, numerically, the result has lower rank than expected.  Here's a simple example that shows this effect with an array `A` that has shape (2, 2):

```
In [56]: A = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1e-12]])                                                                                                  

In [57]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)                                                                                                            
Out[57]: 2

In [58]: B = np.dot(A.T, A)                                                                                                                  

In [59]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(B)                                                                                                            
Out[59]: 1

In [60]: B                                                                                                                                   
Out[60]: 
array([[1.e+00, 0.e+00],
       [0.e+00, 1.e-24]])
```

Note that `set_printoptions` only affects how NumPy arrays are displayed.  It does not affect the precision of computations.

If you lower the tolerance given to `matrix_rank`, you'll recover the estimate of rank 2:

```
In [64]: np.linalg.matrix_rank(B, tol=1e-28)                                                                                                 
Out[64]: 2
```

but I don't know if that is any help for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. You let me find I asked the wrong question. The real problem of my code is not G is deficient-rank, but that G has a negative eigenvalue. I guess it's still a numerical precision issue. So is there any way to increase precision for matrix computation in python?